# Minecraft Skin Messed Up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have just gotten my new computer, because my old one broke. On my old computer, my skin was fine; however on my new computer, it's lost the outer part of the skin. I have redownloaded the skin many times, and I get the same thing for any other server

[image: What the old skin used to look like] [image: What it looks like now]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is just a problem with loading skins, as sometimes this happens to me when I join a server, my skin only shows the inner layer, but soon after it loads the second layer, also I noticed the NPC's behind you don't have there skins ether. One other possibility is that you might have the skin layer turned off in settings.

Thats I can think of that would be wrong, if you have anymore questions feel free to ask me!